# Android - How to implement a List with detail on the same List?

Tags: android, json

I'm using a ListActivity to list events, and i want to show the events and after that i want to show the list of participants on the same List.

[image]

I'm getting JSON data to get the information and one element is a List of the participants.

To show the data i'm using an ArrayAdapter.

```
EventosAdapter adapter = new EventosAdapter(this, R.layout.item_evento, EventosList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The question is, what is the correct way to do this?

Use a LinearLayout inside the ListActivity and to show the detail info use another ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expandable ListView

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Example,
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/